# How to communicate with clients' WCF services (behind firewall) from internet asp.net mvc app?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

Can an internet Asp.net MVC app communicate with client companies' WCF services (hosted on their IIS behind firewall) using SignalR? Otherwise what other .Net technology would help here? Or any third party solutions exists?

Answer (score 1):

There's shouldn't be any problem with communicating a server behind firewalls, as long as the appropriate rules are allowed. Just becareful when applying rules as SignalR has multiple fallback mechanism to support different browsers.

Comment: came across Azure Service bus (relay) can be used for this purpose. you have comment on this.

Comment: why do you need to use another 3-party relay to communicate with your server?

Comment: my global app (wcf/any app) (hosted in DC environment) need to get data from my customer's db using wcf. which is not possible directly due to firewall security. but relay takes care of this.